# Is it possible to use ";" in a query in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and I'm now learning SWI-Prolog, I wonder if I can use ";" in a query to express disjunctive query conditions, e.g., I write this query

```
?-p(a,V1,V2),(V1=b;V1=null),(V2=c;V2=null)
```

and want to check if there exists a fact p/3, in which

1. the first term should be a constant "a";
2. the second term should either be a constant "b" or null;
3. the third term should either be a constant "c" or null.

I wonder if it's the right way to do the query and if there exists a more concise form like maybe

```
?-p(a,(b;null),(c;null))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, "null" here just represents a constant, and can be replaced by any other constant symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Writing the query

```
p(a,V1,V2),(V1=b;V1=null),(V2=c;V2=null).
```

after the `?-`  prompt is just a more direct way of adding the clause

```
myquery(V1,V2) :- p(a,V1,V2),(V1=b;V1=null),(V2=c;V2=null).
```

and *then* asking

```
?- myquery(V1,V2).
```

(`myquery/2` being a newly minted and arbitrarily predicate here).

Incidentally, the clause

```
myquery(V1,V2) :- p(a,V1,V2),(V1=b;V1=null),(V2=c;V2=null).
```

could also be written "multiplied out", i.e.:

```
myquery :- p(a,b,c).
myquery :- p(a,b,null).
myquery :- p(a,null,c).
myquery :- p(a,null,null).
```